# List of dynamic checkbox in Angular and JSON API

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm having trouble rendering dynamic checkboxes with JSON API response.

This 2 ng-repeats:

1. Bringing the listing of categories in BD, and;
2. ng-model with the selected category listing.

Below my HTML code;

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="cats in categorias">
        <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox[item.cats]"><span class="checkbox-material"><span class="check"></span></span></label> {{cats.name}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JSON/API response (1)

```
[
  {"id":"1","id_module":"1","name":"Esportes"},
  {"id":"2","id_module":"1","name":"Entretenimento"},
  {"id":"3","id_module":"1","name":"Terror"},
  {"id":"4","id_module":"1","name":"Drama"}
]
```

JSON response (2)

```
{cats":["1","2"]}
```

I would like that the checkbox stay checked with the response.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: If i'm understanding your use case, what you want is to write a function that receives the value to find in Json2. In that function, iterate the Json2 array and return true if the value is matched and false otherwise. Call this function from Angular's `ngChecked` directive.

Also, since a checkbox only represents boolean values, you should assign the desired checked value to the model with Angular's `ngValue` directive.

Comment: Can you explain what you want exactly in fiddle

Comment: this example:  https://jsfiddle.net/1t142Lbo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have working fiddle, check it

jsfiddle.net/b895j3ay

```js
var app = angular.module("Application", [])
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.roles = [{
    id: 1,
    text: 'guest'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    text: 'user'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    text: 'customer'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    text: 'admin'
  }];
  $scope.isChecked = function(id, matches) {
    var isChecked = false;
    angular.forEach(matches, function(match) {
      if (match === id) {
        isChecked = true;
      }
    });
    return isChecked;
  }
  $scope.user = {
    roles: [2, 4, 3]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Application">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <label ng-repeat="role in roles">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role.id" ng-checked="isChecked(role.id,user.roles)">{{role.text}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked on page load, but I forgot I have to add ng-model, for sending the API and if i click the checkboxes, all are checked.